# WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, streamlit

I'm working on my first personal project -- a bot that schedules and automates an online process using Selenium and takes in user inputs from a website.

I've hosted the website on Streamlit's Cloud community. The website and code work perfectly when I run it on my personal computer but when I upload them to git and reboot the website it gives me:

WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}").

The only difference is that when I run it on my own, a window pops up showing the actual automation happening. On the website nothing pops up which I feel may be a part of the problem.

```
def login(number1, password1):
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

This is the code it gets to when it stops working. ^^^^

```
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/bot/website.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
File "/mount/src/bot/website.py", line 40, in main
    st.session_state["driver"] = vd.login(st.session_state["number"], st.session_state["password"])
File "/mount/src/bot/Driver.py", line 23, in login
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 122, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
```

These are all the error messages^^

I double checked my code -- everything works there. I tried removing Service from the webdriver as well as adding some libraries to my requirements.exe which didn't end up working.